# Find the number of solutions to the equation $z^5+2z^3-z^2+z=\alpha$ in $\{\operatorname{Re}(z)>0\}$ for given $\alpha\in \Bbb R$

Tags: complex-analysis

For a given $\alpha\in$$\mathbb{R}$, find the number of solutions in the half plane $\{Re(z)>0\}$ to the equation: $$ P(z)=z^5+2z^3-z^2+z-\alpha=0$$

Note: The answer is dependent on $\alpha$

I tried to solve the question by defining a half circle with an arbitrary large radius R, and using the argument principle:

Define the closed path: $C=\Gamma_1+\Gamma_2$

Where $\Gamma_1=ix$ for $x\in[-R,R]$, and $\Gamma_2=Re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in[-\frac{π}{2},\frac{π}{2}]$.

From the argument principle, we get:

$\#_{zeros}$-$\#_{poles}$=$\frac{1}{2π}(\Delta_{\Gamma_1}arg(P(z))+\Delta_{\Gamma_2}arg(P(z)))$

For $\Gamma_1$, the change in the argument tends to zero, when R tends to infinity, and for $\Gamma_1$, the change in the argument tends to 5π when R tends to infinity.

P(z) is a polynomial, meaning that $\#_{poles}=0$ and therefore, we get that the number of zeros in equal to $\frac{5π}{2π}=\frac{5}{2}$ which is not a natural number.

In addition, the answer is the same for all $\alpha$ despite what has been told in the question.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I used the fact that the argument of a multiplication is the sum of the arguments and took out the argument of z^5, and I got the change of the argument of z^5, plus the change of the argument of 1+(2z^3-z^2+z-$\alpha$)/z^5 which tends to zero when R tends to infinity

Comment: How did you evaluate $\Gamma_1$?  Very crudely, observe that $P(z)=\big(-z^2-\alpha\big) + \big(z^5+2z^3+z\big)$ where the former is purely real and the latter purely imaginary on $\Gamma_1$. In particular $\text{Im}\big(z^5+2z^3+z\big) \gt 0$ for $R\gt 0$ and $\text{Im}\big(z^5+2z^3+z\big) \lt 0$ for $R\lt 0$ and $\text{Im}\big(z^5+2z^3+z\big)  = 0$ at 3 locations on the imaginary line (use quadratic formula) $\implies$ for $R$ large: the angle is $\approx$ an odd multiple of $\pi$ since the (imaginary) quintic dominates. It also implies $\Gamma_1$ is not valid for multiple $\alpha$'s.

Comment: note: it should have said $\text{Im}\big(z^5+2z^3+z\big) \geq 0$ and $\text{Im}\big(z^5+2z^3+z\big) \leq 0$ for positive and negative $R$ respectively

Comment: Oh I see that for $\alpha=0,1$, $\Gamma_1$ is not valid. Should I use in this case a path that is getting closer to the imaginary line as R tends to infinity, without touching the line?

Comment: If $\Gamma_1$ is valid, the change in argument on it will be -π right? And then we get that there are two zeros on the half-plane?

Comment: assuming $\Gamma_1$ is valid I believe the angle is $\pm \pi$.  Consider $P(0)= -a$ so for $a \gt 0$ we know there is a positive root by Intermediate Value Theorem.  For $a\lt 0$ then $P(0)\gt 0$ which implies a negative root by IVT ($P$ is odd degree real monic after all).